# Apache PDFBox: How can I specify the position of the texts I'm outputting

Tags: java, pdfbox

So basically I already achieved creating a text when generating a pdf on a specific position.

But now my problem is, how do I do it for text that are located on different positions

Expected Generated PDF:

[image: Expected Generated PDF]

```
      contentStream.setLeading(15);     
      contentStream.newLineAtOffset(175, 670);

      String text = "Text 1";
      String text1 = "Text 2";
      String text2 = "Text 3";
      String text3 = "Text 4";
      String text4 = "Text 5";

      contentStream.showText(text);  
      contentStream.newLine();
      contentStream.showText(text1);      
      contentStream.newLine();
      contentStream.showText(text2);      
      contentStream.newLine();
      contentStream.showText(text3);      
      contentStream.newLine();
      contentStream.showText(text4);  
      contentStream.newLine();
      contentStream.showText(text5);
```

Comment: *"how do I do it for text that are located on different position"* - use additional `newLineAtOffset` calls.

Comment: how are you supposed to do that?

I tried putting the newLineAtOffset after contentStream.showText(text4);  and still it doesn't output to what I'm expecting

Comment: I sorted it out, I need to call the beginText and endText all over again. Thanks

Comment: *"I need to call the beginText and endText all over again"* - No, that's not necessary. The only advantage you get from that is that that moves the text insertion point back to the origin, so you can use "absolute" coordinates in your `newLineAtOffset` call.

Comment: Can you site an example for that? I would appreciate if you can, to understand better

Answer (score 4):

In your code you already choose the position for the first line start like this:

```
contentStream.newLineAtOffset(175, 670);
```

Concerning your question

> how do I do it for text that are located on different positions

therefore: You simply use `newLineAtOffset` again!

You have to be aware, though, that `newLineAtOffset(x, y)` does **not** set the new line start to the *absolute* coordinates `x, y` but instead *adds* these values *to* the coordinates of the *previous line start*, hence the `AtOffset` in the method name.

As the *previous line start* coordinates are reset to `0, 0` at the start of a text object (`contentStream.beginText()`), your first `newLineAtOffset` in a text object *appears* to use absolute coordinates.

So if you prefer to use absolute coordinates, you can start a new text object each time you need to move the line start differently than `contentStream.newLine()` does.

If you are ok with relative coordinates, though, you don't need to start new text objects that often but instead use offsets from line start to line start in `newLineAtOffset`, e.g.:

```
try (PDDocument document = new PDDocument()) {
    PDPage page = new PDPage();
    document.addPage(page);

    PDFont font = PDType1Font.HELVETICA;

    String text = "Text 1";
    String text1 = "Text 2";
    String text2 = "Text 3";
    String text3 = "Text 4";
    String text4 = "Text 5";
    String text5 = "Text 6";

    try (PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(document, page)) {
        contentStream.beginText();

        contentStream.newLineAtOffset(175, 670);
        contentStream.setFont(font, 12);
        contentStream.setLeading(15);
        contentStream.showText(text);
        contentStream.newLine();
        contentStream.showText(text1);      

        contentStream.newLineAtOffset(225, 10);
        contentStream.setFont(font, 15);
        contentStream.showText(text2);      

        contentStream.newLineAtOffset(-390, -175);
        contentStream.setFont(font, 13.5f);
        contentStream.setLeading(17);
        contentStream.showText(text3);
        contentStream.newLine();
        contentStream.showText(text5);      

        contentStream.newLineAtOffset(300, 13.5f);
        contentStream.showText(text4);      

        contentStream.endText();

        contentStream.moveTo(0, 520);
        contentStream.lineTo(612, 520);
        contentStream.stroke();
    }

    document.save(TARGET_FILE);
}
```

*([ArrangeText](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-pdfbox2/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/pdfbox2/content/ArrangeText.java#L36) test `testArrangeTextForTeamotea`)*

which results in

[image: Screenshot]

which in turn approximates your image. (I have not counted pixels in your image, so this only is an approximation.)